# Apache - changing document root (Mac)

Tags: macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

I'm just getting started using Apache on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.13), but I'd like to change the document root.  However, I'm not sure I fully understand how to do this, or if it is even possible to set it up the way that I would like to...

For starters, here's the snippet from my httpd.conf file (I haven't made any changes, this is stock)...

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I would like to change the DocumentRoot to the folder where I generally keep my web development work, which is:

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/Stuff/Development
```

I know that the first step is to replace the DocumentRoot and Directory in the .conf file, but this doesn't work - I get the 403 forbidden error - and I'm not sure what to do after that.

My questions...

- Is it possible to set the document root to a folder that is associated with a specific user - me, in this case?  I'm the only user of my machine, and it would be much easier for me to do what I need to if Apache was pointed at that folder.
- If so, what do I need to do other than change the first two lines from the snippet of my .conf file?  Please be specific, as I'm relatively new to working with the terminal.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Several Steps should be taken, have a look: [Configuring Apache Virtual Hosts on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/configure-apache-virtualhost-mac-os-x/) May it help you.

Comment: @triffic Sorry I never said thanks!  This did help me!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can't just change DocumentRoot without giving the permission to new path. If you must use it you have to add chmod +x to each path, in your case those are

User
myname
...
Development

It is not safe to do so. I would user a folder doesn't involved Users.